# Find average amount of times a value appears in table

Tags: sql, pdo

How do I count the average amount of times a given number appears in a database?

```
 id | ...
----------
  1 | ...
  5 | ...
  2 | ...
  3 | ...
  3 | ...
  1 | ...
  6 | ...
  4 | ...
  3 | ...
 ...| ...
```

`id` corresponds to the id of the user. Perhaps the table is for customer orders or donations made by a user. For the above table:

> id 1 = 2 entries
>   id 2 = 1 entry
>   id 3 = 3 entries
>   id 4 = 1 entry
>   id 5 = 1 entry
>   id 6 = 1 entry
>   Average = (2+1+3+1+1+1)/6 = 1.5 entries per user

The average number of orders/donations made per user is 1.5 to give an example.

I could do something like the below:

```
$getTotalEntries = $db->prepare("
    SELECT *
        FROM table
");
$getTotalEntries->execute();
$totalEntries = $getTotalEntries->rowCount();
$getGroupedEntries = $db->prepare("
    SELECT *
        FROM table
        GROUP BY id
");
$getGroupedEntries->execute();
$groupedEntries = $getTotalEntries->rowCount();
$average = $totalEntries/$groupedEntries;
```

I'm hoping for a single SQL request, however. Incidentally, the below gives me the number of occurances of a given id, but I cannot `AVG()` them.

```
$getAverageEntries = $db->prepare("
    SELECT id, COUNT(*)
        FROM table
        GROUP BY id
"); // works, returns the 2,1,3,1,... from before
$getAverageEntries = $db->prepare("
    SELECT AVG(COUNT(*))
        FROM table
        GROUP BY id
"); // won't find aggregate count
```

Comment: You say the id is the user and you want the average per user, but your desired results are the average overall?  `select count(*)/count(distinct id)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
select count(id) / count(distinct id) as avgEntriesPerUser
from table t;
```

The only issue with this would be a `NULL` value for `id`.  If this occurred (and I find it highly unlikely for a column named `id`), then the above ignores those rows entirely.  It can be modified to take this situation into account.

Answer (score 1):

You mean?

```
select avg(countPerID) from (
select id, count(*) as countPerID from table group by id) x
```

Comment: Don't you mean AVG(countPerID)?

Answer (score 1):

```
select avg(a.entryCount)
from (
   select id, count(id) as entryCount
   from <tablename>
   group by id
) a;
```

Answer (score 1):

in SQL you need to do a count to get the number of entries

```
select avg(entries) from(
 Select Distinct Id.tableName, count(Id) As Entries 
         from tableName 
 group by ID)
```